# How to lazyload hook-based logic conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my case, I need to use react-use-websocket in some clients but not others. I would like to lazy load the functionality, including the "react-use-websocket" import, only if needed.

How would you change the following example in order to implement this?

```
import React from 'react';
import useWebSocket from "react-use-websocket";
import Settings from './MyAppSettings';

function App() {
  
  // How do I lazy load websocket only if this variable is true
  const shouldUseWebSocket = Settings.shouldUseWebSocket;

  const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket("wss://some-url.com", {
    // options not shown
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```